# SQL - Create a temp table or CTE of first day of the month and month names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to create a temp table or common table expression based on 2 paremters in a SQL Server 2012 environment

```
@calYear 
@currentYear
```

so if  `@calYear = 5` and  `@currentYear='2014'` 
I would like to generate a temp table of 5 years starting from current year with 4 columns like

```
YearDesc      MonthName     MonthNum     FirstDayOfMonth
2014          Jan           1            1/1/2014
2014          Feb           2            2/1/2014
2014          Mar           3            3/1/2014
...
...
...
2018          Oct           10           10/1/2018
2018          Nov           11           11/1/2018
2018          Dec           12           12/1/2018
```

Is it possible to do a Do While loop efficently? How would I account for the month names?
I'm using a really cumbersome Do While loop to iterate all the months of the year then iterate all the years.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't really a "write code for me" website.  (Also, check out `Convert` for getting interesting date info)

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of these temp tables. There might be a better way to approach your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using a recursive cte:

```
declare @calYear int = 5, @currentYear char(4) = '2014'

;with cte (dt) as (
    select DATEFROMPARTS(@currentyear,1,1) dt
    union all
    select dateadd(month,1,dt) 
    from cte where dt < dateadd(year,@calyear,DATEFROMPARTS(@currentyear,1,1))
    )

select year(dt) YearDesc, datename(month, dt) MonthName, month(dt) MonthNum, dt FirstDayOfMonth 
from cte
order by dt
```

Or using a numbers table: (in this case master..spt_values)

```
declare @calYear int = 5, @currentYear char(4) = '2014'

;with cte2 (dt) as (
    select dateadd(month,number,DATEFROMPARTS(@currentyear,1,1)) dt
    from master..spt_values where type = 'p'
    and number <= 12*@calYear
    )
select year(dt) YearDesc, datename(month, dt) MonthName, month(dt) MonthNum, dt FirstDayOfMonth 
from cte2
order by dt
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I was using a really cumbersome Do While loop to iterate all the months of the year then iterate all the years.

Comment: @stevenjmyu Having numbers/tally/calendar table is really handy. See this http://sql-question.blogspot.se/2012/10/what-is-tally-table-in-sql-server.html for examples.