# SQL Server 2005 simple query to get all dates between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know there are a lot of solutions to this but I am looking for a simple query to get all the dates between two dates.

I cannot declare variables.

Comment: **AT LEAST** show us your table structure, some sample data in that table, and **your efforts** to select the values you want .... after all, we **CANNOT** see your screen, nor read your mind - you have to **SHOW & TELL US!**

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment above, it's just guesswork without your table structures and further detail.  Also, are you using a 3NF database or star schema structures, etc.  Is this a transaction system or a data warehouse?

As a general answer, I would recommend creating a Calendar table, that way you can create multiple columns for Working Day, Weekend Day, Business Day, etc. and add a date key value, starting at 1 and incrementing each day.

Your query then is a very simple sub-select or join to the table to do something like

```
SELECT date FROM Calendar WHERE date BETWEEN <x> AND <y>
```

[How to create a Calender table for 100 years in Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calender-table-for-100-years-in-sql)

There are other options like creating the calendar table using iterations (eg, as a CTE table) and linking to that.

[SQL - Create a temp table or CTE of first day of the month and month names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003833/sql-create-a-temp-table-or-cte-of-first-day-of-the-month-and-month-names)